# Formatting String Value as Monetary Value in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have created a Google Form that has a field where a numeric value is entered by the user (with numeric validation on the form) and is then submitted. When the number (e.g., 34.00) gets submitted, it appears as 34 in the Google spreadsheet, which is annoying but understandable. I already have a script that runs when the form is submitted to generate a nicely-formatted version of the information that was submitted on the form, but I'm having trouble formatting that value as a monetary value (i.e., 34 --> $34.00) using the Utilities.formatString function. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The `values` property of a form submission event as documented in [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) is an array of Strings, like this:

```
['2015/05/04 15:00', 'amin@example.com', 'Bob', '27', 'Bill', '28', 'Susan', '25']
```

As a result, a script that wishes to use any of these values as anything but a String will need to do [explicit type conversion](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp), or coerce the string to number using the unary operator (`+`).

```
var numericSalary = +e.values[9];
```

Alternatively, you could take advantage of the built-in type determination of Sheets, by reading the submitted value from the `range` property also included in the event. Just as it does when you type in values at the keyboard, Sheets does its best to interpret the form values - in this case, the value in column J will have been interpreted as a Number, so you could get it like this:

```
var numericSalary = e.range.getValues()[9];
```

That will be slower than using the `values` array, and it will still provide an unformatted value.

#### Formatting

`Utilities.formatString` uses "sprintf-like" formatting values. If you search the interwebs, you'll find lots of references for `sprint variables`, some of which are helpful. Here's a format that will turn a floating-point number into a dollar-formatted string:

```
'$%.2f'

$ - nothing magic, just a dollar sign
% - magic begins here, the start of a format
.2 - defines a number with two decimal places, but unspecified digits before the radix
f - expect a floating point number
```

So this is your simplest line of code that will do the conversion you're looking for:

```
var currentSalary = Utilities.formatString( '$%.2f', +e.values[9] );
```

Comment: I used your first suggestion which utilizes the formatString function. The only aspect that did not work as I had hoped was formatting with a comma (e.g., $16,000.00), so I just wrote a function to handle that. I had seen a few examples of formatString() that included a comma like Utilities.formatString('$%,.2f', value), but that never worked. If you do know of a variation that includes the comma, I would be interested in trying it out. Thanks.

Comment: One alternative is to use my [SheetConverter Library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/sheetconverter), `Converter.convertCell(1234.56,"$#,###.00")`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct format to get your string into a proper numeric format is as follows:

```
var myString = myString.toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });
```

If you only care about the $ sign and don't need commas the code below (also shown in one of the answers above will suffice.

```
var myString = Utilities.formatString( '$%.2f', myString );
```

In my experience toLocaleString performs sometimes performs strangely in Apps Script as opposed to JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I know this was years ago but might help someone else.
You should be able to add the commas in between with this
`.toLocaleString();` after you format the string decimal then add the '$' sign in the beginning by just concating them together.
Ex:

```
 myString = Utilities.formatString( '%.2f', myNumber );
 myString = '$' + myString.toLocaleString();
```